# Is there a way I can prevent people giving roles higher than their own highest role? (Discord.js V14)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Ok, let's say a person has a role called "Moderator", which has "manage roles" perms. When they want to add a role to another user, they can give a role HIGHER then "Moderator" e.g: the moderator can give the member admin while the moderator doesn't even have that role. Is there a way I can stop that from happening?

Heres my code:

```js
const target = interaction.options.getMember('target');
const rolee = interaction.options.getRole('role');
if (target.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === rolee.name)) {
    await interaction.reply({ content: "Error: User already has this role", ephemeral: true })
}
if (target.user.id === interaction.member.user.id) {
    await interaction.reply({ content: "You cannot give yourself roles.", ephemeral: true })
} else {
    await interaction.reply({
        embeds: [{
            title: 'Role was given',
            description: `<@${target.user.id}> was given  <@&${rolee.id}>`,
            color: '15844367',

            thumbnail: {
                url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1141734104543539220/1141750239984898190/TEST_BOT.jpg'
            },
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'Responsible Awarder',
                    value: `<@${interaction.user.id}>`,
                },
            ],
            footer: {
                text: 'Current version: 0.0.1',
                icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1141734104543539220/1141750630763987015/pooperson.jpg',
            },
        }],

    });

    target.roles.add(rolee)

}
```

This code prevents the moderator from giving himself roles, but he can give higher roles to other people.

[image: here is a photo of my alt not being able to add roles to itself:]

[image: here is a photo of them being capable to add any role to another user]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Discord [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#role-object-role-structure), there's a field for each role that is `position`. I don't do discord.js, but try an `if` statement to see if the user's highest role (in this case, Moderator)'s position is higher than the role they are trying to add.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [position](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Role?scrollTo=position) attribute in the Role class. You can get  the member's highest roles with `target.roles.highest`, and then compare the `position` attribute of the 2 roles. It would be something like:

```js
if (target.roles.highest.position > rolee.position) {
    // block role
}
```

Comment: is there  a way i could just make it not show up? if not i will use that, thanks